# Setting up exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function, interpolation

I want to devise a function $f(x)$ such that $f(4) = 160, f(16)=80, f(28)=40$ and $f(40)=20$, as well as all the other values in between $4-40$. As in, the numbers between $4-12$ have a proportional value between $160-80$. Numbers between $28-40$ have a proportional value between $40-20$ etc.

The values on the left go up linearly and the values on the right go down exponentially.

I hope this makes sense. But would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the numbers on the left are correct?  Because you say they go up linearly, but as you've written them they do not.

Comment: Sorry, linearly was maybe the wrong term. I was just picturing a graph with the numbers right logarithmically proportional to the numbers on the left

Comment: But the numbers on the left do *not* go up linearly. $4 +\color{blue}8 = 12; 12 + \color{red}{16}=28; 28+\color{green}{12}= 40$.  $8, 16, 12$ are different numbers.

Comment: ah sorry. That was daft. It's meant to be 16 not 12. I just changed it there. Yeah so they do go up linearly each time by a step of 12

Comment: "linearly was maybe the wrong term. I was just picturing a graph with the numbers right logarithmically proportional to the numbers on the left"  Linear might be the wrong term but you need *some* term.  You can't have the numbers on the right be any sort of proportion to the numbers on the left if the numbers on the left are jumping about like bunnies with hay fever and no pattern whatsoever.  To answer your question we *do* have to know **WHAT** the numbers on the left *are* doing.  They can't just make it up as they go along.

Comment: Ah.... now we are talking!

Comment: Haha, yeah sorry. I was making things much more difficult than they needed to be.

Comment: Here is how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your $x$-values are spaced linearly and your $y$-values are spaced exponentially, we can find an exponential function based solely on the first two points and it will hold for all of them.  Let $f(x) = a(b)^x$ for unknown $a,b$.  Based on your first two points, we have
\begin{align}
160 &= a(b)^{4}\\
80 &= a(b)^{16}.
\end{align}
Dividing the first equation by the second lets us eliminate $a$:
$$2 = b^{-12} \implies b = 2^{-1/12}.$$

Plugging this back in to either equation (I'll use the second):
$$80 = a(2^{-1/12})^16) = a(2)^{-16/12} = a(2^{-4/3}) \implies a = 80(2)^{4/3}.$$

Putting it all together gives us $$f(x) = 80(2)^{4/3}(2^{-1/12})^{x},$$
which if we want we can rewrite as $$f(x) = 80(2)^{\frac{4}{3} - \frac{x}{12}} = 80(2)^{\frac{16-x}{12}}.$$

If for some reason you wanted to use base $e$ instead this would become $$\ f(x) = 80\left(2\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}e^{\ln\left(2^{-\frac{1}{12}}\right)x}.$$

Comment: Damn that's good. I wish I could do that.

I mean I get it! But I couldn't have worked it out myself. Thanks a lot. I'll put this to good use!

Comment: It's not all that bad, just takes some practice.

Answer (score 1):

So $Left = 4 + 12(t-1)$ or $-8 + 12t$.  And $Right = 160\cdot (\frac 12)^{t-1}$ or $320\cdot (0.5)^t$.

It's probably easiest to leave it as that $x(t) = Left = 12t -8$ while $y(t) = Right = 360\cdot (0.5)^{t}$.

But if you *must* have $Right(Left) = $some function in terms of $Left$ then:

Solve $t$ in terms of $Left$ and plug it into the formula for $Right$.

$Left = -8 + 12t$

$12t = Left +8$

$t = \frac {Left + 8}{12}$

$Right = 360\cdot (0.5)^{t}= 360\cdot (0.5)^{\frac {Left+8}{12}}$

If you like you can shift the offset:

$0.5^{\frac {Left+8}{12} } = 0.5^{\frac {Left}{12}+\frac 23}=[\frac 12]^{\frac 23}0.5^{\frac {Left}{12}}$ s

$Right = [\frac {360}{2^{\frac 23}}]\cdot (0.5)^{\frac {Left}{12}}$

Comment: Ah interesting! Probably a little trickier to grasp than the other solution but think I think I get it. 


Really appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

Take the logarithm of the values on the right column and plot them vs. the values on the left column.

You should obtain quite a straight line.
in any case draw the line that best approximate the graph and you have the parameters of the exponential function you are looking for.

Comment: Okay, I need it in the form of a function for a max/msp patch i'm creating. As in a algebraic function so I can put multiple values through it